# How would I select a name tag with multiple [] in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I try to check a checkbox on my site that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="web[3][feld]" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; opacity: 0;">
```

I try to check it like this:

```
$('[name="web[3][feld]"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Its not working.
How would I do this?

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions. Without success yet. The whole tag looks like this: <input id="kon-8-0" class="styled fwk_g1_k3 fwk_g1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="web[3][feld]" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; opacity: 0;">

Comment: What seems to be the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMD/2/

Comment: Yeah, if the checkbox had been visible it would show it had been checked

Answer (score 1):

Since `[` and `]` are reserved characters you have to escape them

`$('[name="web\\[3\\]\\[feld\\]"]').attr('checked', true);`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMD/)

Comment: No need to escape - `$('input[name="web[3][feld]"]')` works just fine

Answer (score 1):

If *not working* means that [the button only works once](http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMD/6/), it's probably because clicking on the checkbox manually does not update the `checked` attribute. If you use the new recommended method, [prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr), it [seems to work as intuition suggests](http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMD/7/):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('[name="web[3][feld]"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('input[name="web[3][feld]"]').attr('checked', true);
```

You need to mention `input` tag before you are checking for the `name`

See the working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMD/1/)

Comment: Tell me the reason before the down

Comment: So does the OP's example. Explicitly mentioning the `input` tag makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
$('[name^=web]').attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('[name^=web\\[3\\]]').attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('[name^=web\\[3\\]\\[field\\]]').attr('checked', true);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sarwarcse/VMkSc/3/)

Comment: @Markus Döbele, I have updated something. This is it what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name="web\\[3\\]\\[feld\\]"]').attr('checked', true);
```